# Where is the best place to store arrays of strings in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, string

I have a bunch of NSArrays containing a lot of NStrings. Where is the best place to store them, and why - what is the upside of doing it more than other ways? ex. core-data, plist etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them in the Documents Directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSError *error;
BOOL status = [array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

This will save the array and it's contents in a plist.

Core Data is also a good option depending on how you want to access the data it may be a better solution but will be be more involved.

Comment: What kind of document should it be?

Comment: You can name it and it's extension anything you want, just use the same name when you read it in.

Comment: Which is the fastest processing speed? plist or core data

Comment: If you want to access just one string Core Data will be probably be faster. But the question is will the speed make a noticeable difference? Many times the best solution is the easiest. There is a concept of doing the simplest thing that works. Then later if there is a performance problem find it exactly and fix it. "Uncle Bob" has a video where he talks about putting off using a database until it was needed for his FitNesse program only to find out that a database was never needed.

Comment: I'm gonna be accessing all the strings. It's gonna be displayed in a tableview and their values will no change

Comment: IMO Do the simplest thing that could possibly work. From Martin Fowler: [The Value of Simplicity](http://martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html#TheValueOfSimplicity) *Two of the greatest rallying cries in XP are the slogans "Do the Simplest Thing that Could Possibly Work" and "You Aren't Going to Need It" (known as YAGNI). Both are manifestations of the XP practice of Simple Design.*

Comment: I'm wondering about using static nsarray's for this. If he only has 20 or so arrays of 20 or so strings each, would static nsarrays be fine to do the job? what do you think @Zaph

Comment: @Alex Sure if there is no need to save them across launches. But rather than static NSArrays a Data Model is a better solution, a singleton is fine if the data model exist for the entire duration of the apps life, or it could be held by the app delegate for those who equate singletons with killing kittens.